# How do I update a record via params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I want to be able to update a record via params. Something like this:

```
http://domain.com/api/v1/notes/2190/notify?message=test
```

But it just returns a page not found. Pretty standard routes going on:

```
resources :notes, only: [:show] do
  post 'notify'
end
```

My `notify` method looks like this:

```
def notify
  @note = Note.find(params[:id])
  if params[:message]
    render text: @note.update_attributes(message: params[:message])
  end
end
```

Do I need to do anything else to permit this functionality? Any advice at all? I can't figure it out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The routes should be something like:

```
resources :notes, only: :show do
  member do
    get 'notify'
  end
end
```

Comment: That still doesn't permit updating via `curl --data` for some reason.

Comment: @emm: could you update your question with the corresponding curl command?

Comment: It works now but I'm not sure what made it work so I'm leaving it. Can still update it if need be with what I suspect fixed it but it's really out of scope for the question. Hence my vote to close it.